# Validation on combobox when still nothing is selected

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a jquery validation working on a combobox when nothing is selected that a method gets triggered. So you select the filed but you do not choose anything and jump to the next field. Currently the method only gets triggered when I select something in the combobox but not when "nothing" is select (Please select)

My comobox in html is that:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Collection",  new SelectList(Model.TableCollectionDevice.Where(x => x.persona == false), "collection_id" , "collection_displayname"), "Please select",  new { @CssClass="ddl_collection", @id="ddl_collection", @class = "form-control" })
```

I assume the error is that "Please select" has no value like "" and that’s why it does not get triggered.
My jquery looks like that:

```
$.validator.addMethod("selectComboboxCheck", function (value, element)
      {
          console.log("Test"); // Just to see if something gets fired
          console.log($(element).find(":selected").val());
          if ($(element).find(":selected").val() == 0) {
              return false; 
          }
          else return true;
      },
      "Required");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form_import").validate({
        errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
        rules: {
            Collection:{
                required : true ,
                selectComboboxCheck: true
            
            },
```

Any idea how I can fire the method even nothing is selected?

Thanks
Stephan

Edit: It seems with this line are get the correct focus:

```
$("select").blur(function () { $(this).valid() });
```

Comment: I don't understand the use case of a validation for a select box. If you need something selected, just select the first entry on creation. Thats it